# How to show existence of an orthogonal map?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I want to show that the following holds: Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ be given and such that $\|x\|=\|y\|$. There is an orthogonal map $T$ such that $Ty=x$ (a rotation).

How could one justify the latter statement? Probably, this is really easy but at the moment I am stuck on this one. Any (small) hint for a starting point is welcome.

Edit: I don't want to calculate the map directly by using polar coordinates unless there is no other method. I'm looking for a more abstract argument

Comment: Hint: Complete $\frac{x}{||x||}$ to an orthonormal basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$, complete $\frac{y}{||y||}$ to an orthonormal basis $(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ and define $T$ by describing how it acts on $e_i$.

Comment: reflection matrices of the form $2aa^T/a^Ta - I$ or $I - 2bb^T/b^Tb$ with $a = x + y$ and $b = x - y$ should work in all cases.

Comment: @abel, I realize that I didn't lern the householder transformation properly :) So the matrix you construct reflects $y$ on $x$ and vice versa?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1, yes, this matrix is called the householder transformation though it had been known long before householder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 cases:

1. $y=x$
2. $y=-x$
3. $x$ and $y$ linearly independents.

The first and second cases are trivials. ($Id$ and $-Id$).

To last case you can complete $x$ and $y$ to a orthonormal basis and choose a basis change transformation such that $Tx=y$, remember that such transformations are orthornormals.